# Discord.py non-required options being required

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been implementing slash commands to my discord bot with mostly no problems until I introduced options with required=False, and I have no idea how to make them work.
I've tried changing the arrangements, define the args before, then check them and even rewritten the entire command over again with no success.
How can I make the command execute the first cmd7 if only trackname is given, and execute the second if both trackname and artist args are given?

````py
@slash.slash(name='song', description='search for spotify songs', options=[discord_slash.manage_commands.create_option(name='trackname', description='name of the track you\'re searching', option_type=3, required=True), discord_slash.manage_commands.create_option(name='artist', description='track artist\'s name', option_type=3, required=False)])
async def cmd7(ctx:discord_slash.SlashContext, trackname):
    resp_json = sp.search(q='track: ' + trackname, type = 'track', limit=1)
    for track in resp_json['tracks']['items']:
        if str(track['name']).lower() == trackname.lower():
            track_id = track['external_urls']['spotify']
            print(track_id)
            await ctx.send(track_id)
        else:
            await ctx.send('song not found')
async def cmd7(ctx:discord_slash.SlashContext, trackname, artist):
    resp_json=sp.search(q='track: ' + trackname + ', artist: ' + artist, type='track,artist', limit=1)
    for track in resp_json['tracks']['items']:
        if str(track['name']).lower() == trackname.lower():
            track_id = track['external_urls']['spotify']
            await ctx.send(track_id)
        else:
            await ctx.send('song not found')```
````

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PyCord:

```
from discord.commands import Option

async def cmd7(ctx:discord_slash.SlashContext, trackname: Option(str, "The  name of the track you would like to search", required=False)):
```

The first argument: `str` being the type of variable that the user has to input

The second argument being the description of the Option

The final argument `required`: whether it's required or not

Comment: I'm using discord.py and discord-slash, and the problem is that it's trying to execute the first command no matter what, which won't let me have optional choices that you don't have to input